# Trouble merging two simple dot nix files for nix-shell

Tags: nixos, nix

I am new to nix expression. I found two configuration files that I want to use in nix-shell.

Unfortunately I failed to merge them due to my lack of nix expression knowledge. Always end-up with syntax error.

**a.nix** is for setting custom `shellHook`. Here simplified for just setting `$PS1`

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}  }:

with pkgs;

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "python3-shell";
  buildInputs = [ ];

  shellHook = ''
    export PS1="\[\033[1;32m\][nix-shell:\w]\n$ \[\033[0m\]"
  '';
}
```

**b.nix** is for python override. I need this to make [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) work.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

( pkgs.python3.buildEnv.override  {
  extraLibs = with pkgs.python3Packages; [ jedi pyyaml ];
}).env
```

I do understand `a.nix` structures but the syntax in `b.nix` is different.

How should I do it?

Is there any simpler resource to study beside nixos [manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-expression-language)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** with following configuration.

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

let py3s = pkgs.python3.buildEnv.override {
  extraLibs = with pkgs.python3Packages; [ jedi pyyaml ];
};
in stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "python3-shell";
  buildInputs = [ py3s ];

  shellHook = ''
    export PS1="\[\033[1;32m\][nix-shell:\w]\n$ \[\033[0m\]"
  '';
}
```

Still have not fully understand the code but somehow got desire prompt and `jedi-vim` can now see `yaml`

[image]